# WebApp put static HTML/JS files in WAR or in separate Webserver?

Tags: javascript, java, html, tomcat, architecture

I am not sure if this question were already answered somewhere. I dont find something about this.

At the moment i develop a webapplication with a java webservice backend and HTML/JS/CSS frontend. Now i am not sure what to do best with the static html/js/css files?

Put them into a separate apache webserver or put them into the java WAR file and deploy it as one file to the apache tomcat?

What is best practise in this case and what are the main disadvantages and advantages?

Comment: In order to provide a non-opinionated answer different from "it depends", we'll need a lot more information about your situation. Expected load is one of them. What are you intending to optimize for? Performance (of server, browser, or network?), Maintainability? What's the size of your application? etc. - Did you measure and have any problems in one of the areas that I've asked about? Or is this purely hypothetical?

Comment: My question was purely hypothetical... I only want to know the generally advantages and disadvantages. I know that when you have for example a low server load and want to have a portability you better can put the HTML files into the WAR. But what is best practise? Does it depend on what i want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Much of the advice advocating separating the static content from the dynamic content stemmed from when tomcat was atrocious at serving static content.  These days it is fairly straightforward and performant, allowing things like cache-control headers.

If you have enough load to overwhelm tomcat's defaultservlet static content serving, you probably want to look at a CDN for your static content.